# convert html pages to pdf

Tags: php, vb.net, printing, html-table

Im just imagining what the things I can do to make a pdf file out of my localhost files(.php).
I tried using the online conversion tools but it didnt work because they're not on the web definitely.
Can you recommend me of some ways on how I can achieve my goal of converting an html table into pdf and print it using the print function in vb.net?

-I'm using vb.net as my interface for the database program I am making(mysql) utilizing php as the code to manipulate database. I've made use of vb.nets web browser to achieve this. Because I'm still a moron when it comes to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Migradoc / PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=51&Itemid=1) for generating .pdf files to great effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged it as **php** too and in php, we find [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) to be really good to create all sorts of layouts.

[Tutorials](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php)

[Scripts](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux and PHP environment, you might wanna try wkthmltopdf on http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

I have tried it myself and was so pleased with the results of HTML conversion to PDF.

It has a program to run from terminal and it works well with your CSS styles.

But the file is huge and you need to install X Server on your Linux.

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` requires to have the *X libraries* installed, but you don't need a running *X server*.

Answer (score 0):

Prince XML ( http://www.princexml.com/ ) does an incredible job of converting even complex CSS layouts to PDFs. (We use it in combination with TinyMCE so end-users can create PDFs, and the results look great.) The license is fairly expensive, though.

Comment: Is it a program or script to run in a webserver?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes, you can use it on a webserver from the command line. http://www.princexml.com/doc/7.0/command-line/

Comment: Humm, I'm posting here the best solution I have ever found about generate pdf on the fly, and it is totally customizable and run in a webserver, local or online. Great solution --> http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

I used in one project http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/. There is some work with fonts and encoding, but its functional with CSS, images and etc. And today I found mpdf.bpm1.com/ but I didnt try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) or [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Both are open source and use PHP classes for their implementation.